# How to group-by a sequence in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

This is the Input i have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0.0, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.2", "UDP" , 64], 
                                      [2, 0.2, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.3", "UDP" , 64],
                                      [3, 0.8, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.4", "UDP" , 64],
                                      [4, 1.01, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.2", "ARP" , 64],
                                     [5, 1.23, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.3", "UDP" , 64],
                                     [6, 1.44, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.4", "UDP" , 64],
                                     [7, 1.90, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.2", "ARP" , 64],
                                     [8, 2.05, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.3", "UDP" , 64],
                                     [9, 2.3, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.4", "UDP" , 64],
                                     [10, 2.5, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.2", "UDP" , 64],
                                     [11, 2.67, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.3", "ARP" , 64]]),
                            columns=['No.', 'Time','Source', 'Destination', 'Protocol', 'Length'],
                            index =['0', '1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'])
```

This is the output:

```
    No. Time    Source      Destination Protocol    Length
0   1   0.0     192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 UDP           64
1   2   0.2     192.168.1.1 192.168.1.3 UDP           64
2   3   0.8     192.168.1.1 192.168.1.4 UDP           64
3   4   1.01    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 ARP           64
4   5   1.23    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.3 UDP           64
5   6   1.44    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.4 UDP           64
6   7   1.9     192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 ARP           64
7   8   2.05    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.3 UDP           64
8   9   2.3     192.168.1.1 192.168.1.4 UDP           64
9  10   2,5     192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 UDP           64
10 11   2,67    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.3 ARP           64
```

Now i want to group the input by the protocol "ARP". One sequence should appear everytime the ARP Protocol is in the Data.

---

This is what i want:

```
Secquence   No. Time      Source        Destination Protocol    Length
             1  0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.2 UDP           64
             2  0.2      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.3 UDP           64
             3  0.8      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.4 UDP           64
1            4  1.01     192.168.1.1    192.168.1.2 ARP           64
             5  1.23     192.168.1.1    192.168.1.3 UDP           64
             6  1.44     192.168.1.1    192.168.1.4 UDP           64
2            7  1.9      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.2 ARP           64
             8  2.05     192.168.1.1    192.168.1.3 UDP           64
             9  2.3      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.4 UDP           64
            10   2,5     192.168.1.1    192.168.1.2 UDP           64
3           11  2,67     192.168.1.1    192.168.1.3 ARP           64
```

Comment: Please do attach the input/expected outputs as text, not images.

Comment: I have attached it as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with condition and [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html),

```py
cond = df.Protocol == 'ARP'
df.loc[cond, 'Sequence'] = df[cond].groupby('Protocol').cumcount() + 1

print(df)
   No.  Time       Source  Destination Protocol Length   Sequence
0    1   0.0  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.2      UDP     64        NaN
1    2   0.2  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.3      UDP     64        NaN
2    3   0.8  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.4      UDP     64        NaN
3    4  1.01  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.2      ARP     64        1.0
4    5  1.23  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.3      UDP     64        NaN
5    6  1.44  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.4      UDP     64        NaN
6    7   1.9  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.2      ARP     64        2.0
7    8  2.05  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.3      UDP     64        NaN
8    9   2.3  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.4      UDP     64        NaN
9   10   2.5  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.2      UDP     64        NaN
10  11  2.67  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.3      ARP     64        3.0
```

If you want to change `NaN` values with `''` and rearrange columns,

```py
df.loc[df.Sequence.isnull(), 'Sequence'] = ''

cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]

print(df[cols])

   Sequence  No.  Time       Source  Destination Protocol Length
0              1   0.0  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.2      UDP     64
1              2   0.2  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.3      UDP     64
2              3   0.8  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.4      UDP     64
3          1   4  1.01  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.2      ARP     64
4              5  1.23  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.3      UDP     64
5              6  1.44  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.4      UDP     64
6          2   7   1.9  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.2      ARP     64
7              8  2.05  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.3      UDP     64
8              9   2.3  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.4      UDP     64
9             10   2.5  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.2      UDP     64
10         3  11  2.67  192.168.1.1  192.168.1.3      ARP     64
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `df.dropna(subset= ['Secquence'])` or `df[pd.notnull(df['Secquence'])]` if you don't want NA values, but there will be only rows, where the Secqeunce column's value is not NaN in your dataframe.